# Why can't I connect to Dropbox using OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backup, dropbox

I want to store my db backup in my dropbox account every night. For this I'm using Backup + dropbox gem. My Ruby version is 1.8.7p358 and Rails 2.3.8 and I'm using a Mysql database.

Here is my error in console

```
[2012/10/26 11:25:28][error]ModelError: Backup for My Backup (my_backup) Failed!
[2012/10/26 11:25:28][error]   An Error occured which has caused this Backup to abort before completion.
[2012/10/26 11:25:28][error]   Please review the Log for this Backup to determine if steps need to be taken
[2012/10/26 11:25:28][error]   to clean up, based on the point at which the failure occured.
[2012/10/26 11:25:28][error]   Reason: OAuth::Unauthorized
[2012/10/26 11:25:28][error]   401 Unauthorized
```

Here is my code

```
    Backup::Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do

      database MySQL do |db|
        db.name               = "app_development"
        db.username           = "user"
        db.password           = "pass"
        db.host               = "127.0.0.1"
      end

      store_with Dropbox do |db|
        db.api_key    = 'nvpsggrunft0'
        db.api_secret = '71dvvvdx48hy3'
        db.path       = '/backups'
        db.keep       = 80
        db.timeout    = 443
      end


      store_with FTP do |server|
        server.username = 'aadddn'
        server.password = 'tdsddsd'
        server.ip       = 'Ip Address'
        server.port     = 21
        server.path     = ''
        server.keep     = 30
        server.passive_mode = true
      end

      compress_with Gzip do |compression|
        compression.best = true
        compression.fast = false
      end

      notify_by Mail do |mail|
        mail.on_success           = true
        mail.on_failure           = true

        mail.from                 = 'xyx@abc.com'
        mail.to                   = 'sumit.munot@cipher-tech.com'
        mail.address              = 'mail.abc.com'
        mail.port                 = 26
        mail.domain               = 'abc.com'
        mail.user_name            = 'abc'
        mail.password             = 'gvgfgxvxv'
        mail.authentication       = 'login'
        mail.enable_starttls_auto = false
      end  
end
```

I am running the following command in console for taking the backup

```
backup perform -t my_backup -c /home/xyz/my_workplace/abc/lib/Backup/config.rb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oauth authorization URL will display on `previous version of Drop box gem`. We can simply solve the problem by clicking on the link it authorize your machine. And back will successfully saved on Drop box.